# Compress Image bytes in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

How can be compress the image taken in `Xamarin.Android` using [CameraSourcePreview](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker), the byte in the method `OnPictureTaken` is too big.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it by converting the Bitmap to a compressed JPG file.  Also in this example is how to save the compressed JPG file to the picture gallery and make it immediately available through USB/Windows via an Android Media Scan.  Hope this helps!

```
    public void OnPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        var bmp = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(data, 0, data.Length);
        SaveBitmapAsJPEG(bmp, 75);
    }

    public void SaveBitmapAsJPEG(Bitmap pBitmap, int pnQuality = 85) {

        Java.IO.File jFolder = GetCreatePhotoAlbumStorageDir("MyPhotoAlbum");
        Java.IO.File jFile = new Java.IO.File(jFolder, $"Photo_{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")}.jpg");

        // "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyPhotoAlbum/Photo_20190526112410.jpg", which is the following via Windows/USB...
        // "Internal shared storage\Pictures\MyPhotoAlbum\Photo_20190526112410.jpg"

        using (var fs = new FileStream(jFile.AbsolutePath, FileMode.CreateNew)) {
            pBitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, pnQuality, fs);
        }

        SavePictureToGallery(jFile);

        Android.Util.Log.Info("MyApp", $"Picture saved using SaveBitmapAsJPEG() at {jFile.AbsolutePath}");

        // Request the media scanner to scan a file and add it to the media database (Make file visible/available through USB connection in Windows Explorer)
        var f = new Java.IO.File(jFile.AbsolutePath);
        var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
        intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(f));
        Application.Context.SendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    public Java.IO.File GetCreatePhotoAlbumStorageDir(string psAlbumName) {
        // Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory.  Will create if it doesn't exist.
        var dir = new Java.IO.File(Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryPictures), psAlbumName);
        if (!dir.Exists())
            dir.Mkdirs();
        return dir;
    }

    private void SavePictureToGallery(Java.IO.File pFile) {
        var intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
        intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(pFile));
        StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
```

Note that you could change the format to PNG if desired by changing the "CompressFormat" to .Png, and naming the file accordingly.